# Код .py, скомпелированный pyinstaler, windows defender считает за троян Trojan:Win32/Bearfoos.B!ml

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

Сегодня я компилировал код .py с помощью pyinstaler, и как только я скомпилировал и переместил файл, *windows defender* обнаружил `Trojan:Win32/Bearfoos.B!ml`, до этого такого не возникало, я так и не понял, стоит ли беспокоиться, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: А это точно не троян?))

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит бояться, WinDefender иногда выдает ложную тревогу.

Добавьте папку, в которую идет собираемое приложение, в исключения антивируса.

Comment: на сам вопрос-то вы не ответили.

Comment: Отвечаю. Не стоит бояться, WinDefender иногда выдает ложную тревогу.

Comment: Как ни странно, но всё так, у меня все проекты лежат в C:\Source, и эта папка в исключениях антивируса. Это нормально, я считаю.

Comment: pyinstaler тоже в C:/Source? Возможно pyinstaler внутри себя протаскивает файлы проекта через временные папки, которые где-то в другом месте.
Посмотрите в истории дефендера в какой папке находился файл с трояном.